# PL SQL variable reference in a column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a requirement where i have a table column containing an expression that should get appended as a where clause  to a select stmt in a procedure.

The expression has reference to variables available in the procedure.

```
Declare 
Query varchar2(4000);
Expression varchar2(4000);
Value varchar2(10):= 'abc';
Valuex varchar2 := 'def';
 ... n number of variables declared
 Cursor c1 is select expression from tableabc where some condition;
Begin
Expression := output of c1 cursor
Query := ‘select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 ';
 Query := query || expression;
-- now i will use a ref cursor to evaluate query
End;
```

Table abctable has a expression column thta stores :

And 'abc'=value

The value being referred in this expression is the one declaree in pl sql block.

How can i achieve this as this is not working.
I want the value in expression column to be replaced with the one available in pl sql block. I dont want to use replace function as expression column can refer valuex variable or any of the n variable declared in pl sql block. Can the expression be stored in the column in a way that once retrieved in pl sql block it gets replaced with the variable value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare 
  Query varchar2(4000);
  Value varchar2(10):= 'abc';
  c1 sys_refcursor;
Begin
  select 'select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 ' || expression 
          into query
  from tableabc where some condition;

  -- now i will use a ref cursor to evaluate query
  -- suppose the expression looks like "and col1 = :v and col2 = :v"
  open rc for query using value;
  loop
    -- fetch
    -- exit when rc%notfound;
    -- process
  end loop;
  close rc;  
End;
```

Comment: If the expression is like : and 'abc' = value , this value is not getting replaced with the one available in pl sql block

Comment: @Anshoo How it should be replaced? It's not mentioned in your question. Is it always varchar2?

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the block. Let me know if its still vague.

Comment: @Anshoo I've updated my answer. You may use USING clause, but I'm not sure whether it will work for you (if expression returns dynamic number of conditions with various values). See here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems034.htm

Comment: I cant use bind variables as well . Expression can return dynamic no of conditions with diff variables